# error occurred when binarization based ROI algorithm with OpenCV in JAVA

Tags: java, opencv, roi

when implementing ROI algorithm to binarize images in JAVA by using OpenCV，exception threw. can anybody help me figure out bugs among my code snippets?

```
System.loadLibrary(org.opencv.core.Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
String filename = "path/to/image";
Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread(filename, Imgcodecs.IMREAD_COLOR);
int ch = 255, cw = 255; //---small block
int h = image.rows(), w = image.cols(); //---height vs width
Mat gray = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(image, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY); //--to gray

//-----handle every small block
for (int row = 0; row < h; row += ch) {
    for (int col = 0; col < w; col += cw) {
        Rect roi_rect = new Rect(col, row, cw, ch); //------small block:rectangle
        Mat roi = new Mat(gray, roi_rect);
        Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(roi, roi, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 127, 10); //----binarization
        roi.copyTo(gray.submat(roi_rect));//----replace original block
    }
}

HighGui.imshow("binary", gray);
```

exception messages as follows:

`OpenCV(4.7.0-dev) Error: Assertion failed (0 <= _colRange.start && _colRange.start <= _colRange.end && _colRange.end <= m.cols) in cv::Mat::Mat, file C:\GHA-OCV-2\_work\ci-gha-workflow\ci-gha-workflow\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 776`

`Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.7.0-dev) C:\GHA-OCV-2\_work\ci-gha-workflow\ci-gha-workflow\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:776: error: (-215:Assertion failed) 0 <= _colRange.start && _colRange.start <= _colRange.end && _colRange.end <= m.cols in function 'cv::Mat::Mat']`

It threw exception at `Mat roi = new Mat(gray, roi_rect)`. What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The violated assertion is:

```
(
    0 <= _colRange.start &&
    _colRange.start <= _colRange.end &&
    _colRange.end <= m.cols
)
```

Possibilities:

- Your ROI has negative size (start > end)
- your ROI is out of bounds of the parent Mat
- the parent Mat has zero size (and the ROI does not)

You fix that by figuring out which it is, and then figuring out why that is.

Comment: by setting  col < w-cw; row < h-ch respectively, the exception can be avoided , but resulting in few blocks of image intact. so how to shuffle all the image without out- of-range exception? It 's a bit tricky!

Comment: calculate ROI size in each iteration, to be within bounds. will require use of `min()` function and probably subtraction/difference

Comment: Christoph Rackwitz, thanks again.I need to give it more thought.